# Installing HomeBrew `.app` on M1

Tags: applications, homebrew, big-sur, apple-silicon

I am using MBA M1 with macOS Big Sur v11.2.1.

Recently discovered that the program `mpv` is now available natively for M1 macs through `brew`. When I do `brew install mpv` then `mpv` is surely installed and it is indeed native to M1. But the problem is that there is no `.app` for it and everytime I want to run a video I have to necessarily open terminal and do `mpv \path\ to\ file` which I want to avoid. So, searching around I found that the new way to do this is to use the `--cask` option. But when I do an install using the said option, `mpv` is the `Intel` version.

How do I get the native version to work as a regular app? As I understand it, `cask` option is merely combining all the files into an `.app` format and it should not really affect anything. In fact, one should be able to do this fairly easily, without using `cask`, given the right kind of information. Please help me get this working.

Comment: @jballin there also seems to be an app/gui version, see https://mpv.io/installation/

Comment: @nohillside as far as i can see those are all non-native to silicon macs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last point of cask combining the files misses one key step. Someone else has to do the work to assemble and package that app. Homebrew doesn't do that assembly automagically.

I've installed mpv on three machines and your results are the same as I get - Intel Big Sur has a cask, M1 does not. Both get the command line binary.

Unless and until someone sends a pull request to add an M1 version of the cask for this package, you'll want to use a different tool or installation method.

Comment: I concur. Some digging around sent me to the cask page for installation (which is sort of hidden). The default installation page from a simple web search sends us to the binary M1 version. Thank you for your confirmation as well.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach using Automator, developed and tested on an M2 MacBook Pro, working as of November 2023.

This approach uses no special **homebrew** commands or complex build steps so should continue to work, unless the `mpv` command line options change or Apple make some seriously breaking changes to Automator...

1. install **mpv** using **homebrew** as usual: `homebrew install mpv`

This installs the Apple silicon version of `mpv` when run on an Apple silicon machine.

2. Open **Automator** and create a project of type `Application`
3. Add a `Run Shell Script` action from the **Library**
4. Change the **Pass input** option from `to stdin` to `as arguments`
5. Paste the following script into the step:

```
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
   /opt/homebrew/bin/mpv --force-window --idle &
else
   /opt/homebrew/bin/mpv "$1" &
fi
```

6. Save the project to your **Desktop**, ensuring it is saved in *Application* format

**NOTE:** *When I tried to save my project directly into `Applications`, **Automator** seemed to hang every time; saving to `Desktop` and moving the file to `Applications` later was my workaround for this*

7. (*optional*) Find/Create an mpv icon you like and copy/paste it into the icon of the "*Get Info*" **Finder** window for your saved file
8. (*optional*) Open your `Applications` folder in **Finder** and drag/drop your app file to `Applications`

You can now launch an `mpv` window using the *Automator* app you just created, use *Open With* to launch with a selected video file or even associate your app with files having a specific extension, just as with the regular app bundle.

If there are updates to **mpv** applied using **homebrew**, the script in your **Automator** application will continue to work, unless the command line options for starting a new session without a video change or an updated **homebrew** formula results in the `mpv` binary changing name or location.

### Intel Machines

The same approach should also work on an Intel system, if you want the convenience of using homebrew to manage your mpv installation but also want an app icon.  However, you may need to adjust the script to reflect the different location that **homebrew** uses for files on *Intel MacOS* vs *Apple Silicon*.

To find the path to your `mpv` binary, after installing with **homebrew**, use `which mpv` in a terminal.